# Python get http trailers

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-headers

How do I get HTTP trailer response headers with python?  I am using `requests.get` and I am unable to get some of the X-Content-Type or X-Status.  When I use `curl` with `-i` though, I get these responses.  Do I need to send a specific header or parameter?  I tried sending `TE: trailers` but it doesnt seem to do anything.

Some sample code:

```
import requests

url = "some_api_endpoint"
params = {"param1": "val1"}
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "TE": "trailers"}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
print("Status: {}".format(response.status_code))
print("Content: {}".format(response.content.decode('utf-8')))
print("Headers: {}".format(response.headers))
print("Reason: {}".format(response.reason))
```

Output:

```
Status: 200
Content:
Headers: {'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
Reason: OK
```

curl command

```
curl -k -i <url>?<params> -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Output:

```
TP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

X-Status: Some Error
```

I would like to get the `Some Error` or just even the header `X-Status` above from python.  Basically got the 200 from the server and while streaming some of the response, it hit an error in the middle, causing the error. Unfortunately, I cant get this message easily in python.

Comment: Do you want to know how to access the headers sent or are they missing in the response?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I would like to extract them from the response somehow.  They arent found in the `response.headers`.  Assuming `response` is the requests.get() object

Comment: Then they are missing and the server did not send them. Why can't be said with the information you gave

Comment: But as mentioned above, doing the same exact url and params with curl, along with the `-i` flag will get the information I want.  So I am just confused why I am not getting it with python's requests.  What is curl sending differently?

Comment: You have to give some details that allow us to debug the problem: code, request, response data, curl command and output...

Comment: @KlausD. I edited the question, please see above

Comment: If there's an empty line before `X-Status-Error` it is not a valid header. A double linebreak indicated the beginning of the body. The response of the server might be faulty.

Comment: @KlausD. If its not a valid header, what could it be? And could i still somehow get it using requests?

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0444/#request-trailers-and-chunked-transfer-encoding

> Request Trailers and Chunked Transfer Encoding

> When using chunked transfer encoding on request content, the RFCs allow there to be request trailers. These are like request headers but come after the final null data chunk. These trailers are only available when the chunked data stream is finite length and when it has all been read in. **Neither WSGI nor Web3 currently supports them.**

About the **requests** library there's nothing better:

- https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2281
- https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3613

As stated there Trailers is a very rarely used HTTP functionnality.

It's quite complex to implement well (as you must ensure you do not parse here any header that would alter the size of the body like Content-Length and Transfer-encoding).

So they are really few parsers that implement trailers and very few occurences in the HTTP messages nowadays (but you have one, feel sorry for you :-) ).